# Item Response Theory alternatives?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, modeling, model, item-response-theory

What are other approaches than Item Response Theory to model learning of students in standardised tests?

Comment: There is too little information for you to get a good answer. For starters, why do you look for an alternative and ẃhat is the setup and goal of whatever you have in mind?

Comment: While I agree with @Momo that this is a general question, I disagree that this is a poor question: you might simply expect to receive very general answers. If you want more detail, Momo's suggestion of adding detail is a good one.

Comment: I'm just researching for new ideas about how one can model a student performance in standardised test like SAT.

Comment: Basically [classical test theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_test_theory) is an alternative (or rather the other way around). Alternative in what sense? This is too broad to be answerable...